# Create a horizontal line between ListBoxItems (horizontally oriented ListBox)

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to create a listbox like this:

-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----

The |'s are my listboxitems which I have separated using margins. This works fine. What I want is the listbox to have a background that contains this line. Or at least have it in the background. I tried a separator but that is not what I want because that is also clickable since I used it in the itemtemplate.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm trying to create a timeline like control. I now fixed it using this:

```
  <ListBox.Template>
      <ControlTemplate>
            <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black">
                  <Grid>
                        <Rectangle Height="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Fill="Black"/>
                        <ScrollViewer Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                              <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                        </ScrollViewer>
                  </Grid>
            </Border>
       </ControlTemplate>
  </ListBox.Template>
```

This works fine in a testproject, but I'm having some problems in my main project. The rectangle remains under the scrollviewer. Well... making progress. Hope to fix this thing soon.

Thanks for your answers so far!

Comment: and just putting the rectangle *after* the ScrollViewer ?

Comment: The vertical items have to be on top :-) Works in a testproject, not in my other code. I'll the xaml a look when I have time for that.

Comment: note that if you want a part of your template not to be clickable, you might use IsHitTestVisible = False

Comment: I made the background of the scrollviewer transparant. Doesn't feel right, works the way I want it to work however.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a style with a control template to the ListBox items.

```
 <Style x:Key="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
   <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
   <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
   <Setter Property="Template">
     <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
          <Border Name="Border"
                  BorderThickness="1,0"
                  BorderBrush="Black"
                  Padding="2"
                  SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
            <ContentPresenter />
          </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
     </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
 </Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Border control is intended for this type of decorative lines. The side's thickness are independently set, so use just one side for a single vertical line. On a related note, have you tried using a Grid control for your layout instead of margins?

Comment: I didn't give that a try Sinthia. I'm setting the left margins based on a difference in time.